# After importing another library getting below error in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to i phone programming.Can any one tell me what is meaning of this below error.I have create custom static universal library and importing in project and in other linker flag i have added -ObjC.Its working fine. After that i have added one more library file which client given after adding that file if run project its showing below error.I have searched in google i didnt get any solution for this issues.So Please tell me how to slove this issues.

```
Ld /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EsloverAlipay-dzdjgbqpdlhzpndnscpqaxomafeg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EsloverAlipay.app/EsloverAlipay normal i386
    cd /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EsloverAlipay-dzdjgbqpdlhzpndnscpqaxomafeg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay -L/Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay -F/Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EsloverAlipay-dzdjgbqpdlhzpndnscpqaxomafeg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EsloverAlipay-dzdjgbqpdlhzpndnscpqaxomafeg/Build/Intermediates/EsloverAlipay.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EsloverAlipay.build/Objects-normal/i386/EsloverAlipay.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -lssl -lEsloverloginsdkalipay -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlipayRsaLib.a -framework Foundation -lcrypto -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EsloverAlipay-dzdjgbqpdlhzpndnscpqaxomafeg/Build/Intermediates/EsloverAlipay.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/EsloverAlipay.build/Objects-normal/i386/EsloverAlipay_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EsloverAlipay-dzdjgbqpdlhzpndnscpqaxomafeg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EsloverAlipay.app/EsloverAlipay

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AlixPaylib._target in:
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(AlixPaylib.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(AlixPaylib.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AlixPaylib._seletor in:
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(AlixPaylib.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(AlixPaylib.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AlixPaylib._installType in:
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(AlixPaylib.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(AlixPaylib.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AlixPaylib._serverUrl in:
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(AlixPaylib.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(AlixPaylib.o)
duplicate symbol _k_DefaultModel in:

    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(ALPToastView.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(ALPToastView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ALPToastView in:
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(ALPToastView.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(ALPToastView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Alipay_Reachability.reachabilityRef in:
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(Reachability.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Alipay_Reachability.localWiFiRef in:
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(Reachability.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Alipay_Reachability in:
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(Reachability.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(Reachability.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Alipay_Reachability in:
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib.a(Reachability.o)
    /Users/racitsolutionspvtltd/Desktop/EsloverAlipay/EsloverAlipay/alipay/AlixPaylib_arc.a(Reachability.o)
ld: 116 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: So the term "duplicate symbol" means nothing at all to you?

Comment: Ohh ya thanks for giving replay u r correct i have two Lib .Now its working fine thank u very much @Shai

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're importing the same (virtually) library - one ARC, one NON ARC. Remove one of them